# How do I make a random enemy spawner?

Tags: c#, monogame

This may be a lil stupid, but I'm making an endless runnner and I can't make my obstacles spawn properly...

To elaborate, I have 3 different obstacles, and I can't get them to be picked at random, as the next to appear - if that makes sense!
I also can't get the distance between each obstacle to be random, either.

For you to get an idea of what kind of game I'm making, I'm trying to make it somewhat of the same layout as Chome Dino (https://chromedino.com)

Note: I would provide some code, but I have nothing for this issue - I just kinda need some source code that will work ;p I've been spending several days trying to find some code that works, but nothing so far.
Oh, I do have 2 classes that are my Obstacle generator and the jumping function.
If code is needed, I'm happy to provide it!

Everything I've researched usually were for Unity, which I've had some insane frustrations with, hence why I'm not using it.

I tried making an array that would hold my 3 obstacles, with the idea of picking an index at random, but that threw the error CS0021 - "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ObstacleGenerator'.

I also tried having:

```
int obstacles = random.Next(0, 3);
```

Then saying:

```
if (obstacles == 0)
{
    obstacle1.Update(gameTime);
}
else if (obstacles == 1)
{
    obstacle2.Update(gameTime);
}
else if (obstacles == 2)
{
    obstacle3.Update(gameTime);
}
```

In theory, that should pick a number at random (between 0 and 3), and whichever is picked, that's the obstacle that should start moving. The issue is that the random.Next() doesn't just pick one random number - it's constantly picking, so the obstacles move, but jerkily. Is that what's supposed to happen with random.Next ???
If so, is there a better way to get the enemies to get picked at random?

I'm using C#, Visual Studio with a MonoGame template. Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: There's a Random class in the base System namespace. Explore using this class to randomly choose one of your obstacles. This can also be used to choose a random interval to offset your obstacles. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0

Comment: Also, try putting your obstacles as new objects in a List after they've spawned, then remove them from the list when they're out of bounds again, that way, multiple of the same obstacle can exist.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
Blue: I've just edited my post which explains my problems with the Random class. 

Steven: I've tried putting my obstacles into an array, but because they come from my Obstacle Generator class (which is in a different tab to the Main), it throws error CS0021

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding Steven's advice.

Use the random number generator to choose and offset a random obstacle from your generator, but add that obstacle to an obstacle array. Adding obstacles to an array means a few things: The offset can be different for each obstacle, you can have a collection of obstacles including duplicates, and you can remove them as they go out of bounds. You shouldn't continue to apply random to generated obstacles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, why not use a [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0) structure for your obstacles. [Enqueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.enqueue?view=net-7.0) an obstacle when it spawns on screen and then in your main Update loop, iterate through the Queue with a foreach loop to update each obstacle. When an obstacle leaves the screen [Dequeue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.dequeue?view=net-7.0) it.

A Queue seems perfect because it obeys FIFO rules (first in first out) which corresponds to your obstacles entering and leaving the playing field.

As for when to spawn them you could keep it simple for now, have a decrementing counter in your main Update loop, when it reaches zero, spawn another random obstacle and add it to the Queue; at the same time reset the counter to a random number between say 200 and 400 so you get another obstacle at a random time in the future.

Comment: thank you for your reply! In theory this works, but when I used a foreach loop it sent an error:
Exception Unhandled.

Comment: edit:
thank you for your reply! In theory this works, but when I used a foreach loop it sent an error:

Exception Unhandled.
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not exectute.'

I used "obstacles.Enqueue(obstacle1);" in the LoadContent class, and the foreach loop in the Update class.... Am I doing something wrong?

I used "foreach (var obstacle in obstacles)
           {
                 ob1X--;
                 if (ob1X + 20 <= 0)
                 { obstacles.Dequeue(): }
            }

I think I've messed up! Please help

Comment: I've posted another question regarding the error, as the above comment is messy :D

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564433/c-sharp-foreach-is-throwing-collection-was-modified-error

Comment: this works now - My problem was that I was trying to modify the queue within the foreach loop - which isn't possible -  so I just made my obstacles move forward in the foreach, then Dequeue'd them below the loop :)

My full code is in the link I posted in the comment above