# foreach is throwing 'Collection was modified' error

Tags: c#, foreach, monogame

I'm using a monoGame template in Visual Studio, and I'm making an endless runner (similar to Chrome Dino).
In the `LoadContent` class I've used `Enqueue` to put my obstacles into a `Queue` list.
Note: I've only given the code for the first obstacle because the code for the others is exactly the same :)

Here's my Queue code:

```
Queue<Texture2D> obstacles = new Queue<Texture2D>();
```

And my code in LoadContent to add my obstacles to the list:

```
obstacles.Enqueue(obstacle1);
```

Then in my `Update` class, I have the following code, which is where the error is:

```
foreach (var obstacle in obstacles)
{
    ob1X--;

    if(ob1X + 20 <= 0)
    {
        obstacles.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

when I run the code, it highlights the word `in` and throws the error:

*Exception Unhandled
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'*

Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing an inportant part?

I got advised to use this method to make the obstacles come onto the screen, but this error is stopping me from continuing. Please help!

Comment: try to use for statement loop backwards.

Comment: The error is clear. You're modifying the query while iterating it. Which is the next item in the iteration if you *remove* items?

Comment: Do you really want to dequeue items? If so, you don't need the `foreach` loop. Use `TryDequeue` until the queue is empty, eg `while(queue.TryDequeue(out var item){ .... }`

Comment: You could perhaps create a clone, then loop through the clone whilst removing the items from the original.

Comment: The question's code retrieves the first 20 items. If you don't really need to dequeue, you can use LINQs `Take`, eg `var items=queue.Take(20);` to take the first 20 items. If you do want to dequeue `while(queue.TryDequeue(...) && count-- >0){...}`.

Comment: Why do you need `foreach` at all? you don't use `obstacle`

Comment: thank you all for your replies but they're not fixing the problem :( 
All I'm trying to do with this code is to make the obstacles move from the right to the left and then get dequeued once they disappear on the left

Comment: Dmitry, I got advised to use foreach, and it should work, it just doesn't like what's in the brackets

Comment: change your foreach to a for loop, it will not throw an error but you will have to manage your iterations

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems overly complicated, you do not need to be using a foreach loop at all then as it seems you are simply minusing the number of obstacles from the viewport width?

If this is the case then you will be doubling the memory required to store obstacles as each obstacle is assigned to obstacle in your loop.

```
ob1X -= obstacles.Count();

if(ob1X <= 0)
{
    obstacles.Dequeue();
    ob1X = viewportWidth;
    obstacles.Enqueue(obstacle1);
}
```

Your code in your answer also doesn't match you OP where `ob1X + 20` has to be less than 0 (a better way to write it would be `obj1X < -20`)

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of researching and trial and error, I've discovered that you can't modify the contents of the queue within a **foreach** loop.
To elaborate, the error was getting thrown because I was trying to **Dequeue** within the **foreach** loop.
This code isn't allowed:

```
foreach (var obstacle in obstacles)
{
    ob1X--;

    if(ob1X <= 0)
    {
        obstacles.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

So what I did was take the if statement out of the **foreach** and put it under the loop.
With just the **obstacles.Dequeue();** , it was telling me the queue was empty.
I had to **Enqueue** it after I **Dequeue**'d it for this to work.

NOTE: the if statement is saying "when the obstacle reaches the left of the screen, take it off the queue, move it back to the right of the screen and add it back to the queue." This set-up will let me modify what comes onto the screen.

My final code looks like this:

```
foreach(var obstacle in obstacles)
{
    ob1X--;
}

if(ob1X <= 0)
{
    obstacles.Dequeue();
    ob1X = viewportWidth;
    obstacles.Enqueue(obstacle1);
}
```

I found this web page very helpful in understanding how Queues work, and it's not too technical to cause confusion!
https://codebuns.com/csharp-advanced/queue/

Hopefully this will help anyone else who is in the same situtation :)

Comment: The problem with your code to start with was you were using the wrong tool for the job. You still are. You've just managed to not spring the same error. What would be really helpful here is a concise description of what you're doing to be able to suggest the right approach. Perhaps update the question with more code to give a better context?